# Django and keeping coordinates

Tags: django, google-maps, django-models

What would be the ideal way of keeping location coordinates as a model field inorder to use at Google Maps at Django?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd think it's probably easier to keep the latitude and longitude as separate [FloatFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#floatfield)

Comment: What would be the implementation so I it is needed to add origin and destination? Do you think it should be added separately?

Answer (score 15):

Here's the code I use for storing Google's Lat/Lon

```
lat = models.FloatField(_('Latitude'), blank=True, null=True)
lon = models.FloatField(_('Longitude'), blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Old post, but what is the "_" for infront of the "('latitude')?

Comment: @Mhsmith21: _ is a common used shortcut for gettext-functions. E.G. `from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/)

Answer (score 13):

Possible a better idea is to store in decimal field

```
lat = models.DecimalField(_('Latitude'), max_digits=10, decimal_places=8)
lng = models.DecimalField(_('Longitude'), max_digits=11, decimal_places=8)
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12504340/1977197

Answer (score 10):

If you are only ever going to store/retrieve a pair of lat/lon coords a `models.FloatField` pair is probably fine. If you planned to do spatial queries, you should consider using some of the special fields provided by [GeoDjango](http://geodjango.org/), which adds support for [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/) and geographic data.