# Precision lost when storing CLLocationDegrees in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ios, double, core-location, precision

I'm working on a little app that stores *Placemarks* specified by iOS devices, into a MySQL backend. When a device saves a new *Placemark*, it is INSERTed into the DB and the newly generated ID is sent back to the client. If another device attempts to save the same *Placemark*, the server needs to figure out that it already exists in the DB, and instead of INSERTing and generating a new ID, it needs to send back to the client the existing ID for that Placemark.

2 *Placemarks* are the same if they have identical:

- name
- latitude
- longitude

Therefore the server attempts to identify if the submitted Placemark already exists by issuing

> SELECT id FROM Placemark WHERE name=x, latitude=y, longitude=x

- In iOS, `latitude` and `longitude` are in degrees and of type `CLLocationDegrees` as reported by `<CoreLocation>`
- In MySQL, `latitude` and `longitude` are defined as `DOUBLE`

**The problem:**

Precision is lost when storing coordinates, for instance:

`latidude` of `50.09529561485427` is stored as `50.0952956148543`

`longitude` of `-122.9893130423316` is stored as `-122.989313042332`

**The question:**

Can I use a different data type in MySQL so as to store each coordinate intact?

**Notes:**

- I can't store coordinates as `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` because I need to be able to say `SELECT placemarks coordinates BETWEEN x AND y`, or perform other arithmetic SELECTs
- I can't use MySQL's spatial extensions because portability is an issue, and also because to my understanding, spatial data types are very slow when used as keys (and my use case requires SELECT by coordinates)

Any help appreciated

Comment: Aside from your question, entering both coordinates into Google Maps gives me an almost identical location (it's off by a couple of feet). Do you really need that much accuracy?

Comment: Hi DTs. I recommend closing this question as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504208/what-mysql-data-type-should-be-used-for-latitude-longitude-with-8-decimal-places/12504340#12504340 -- you can adapt that answer to your problem with CLLocationDegrees pretty easily. Regards.

Comment: @Scott Remember, I use those coordinates in my WHERE clauses. They need to remain intact not because I need to identify a Placemark super accurately, but because they are used as keys in subsequent searches.

Comment: @DTs floating point data is rarely good choice for any type of key value - it is even almost impossible to precisely compare if two floats are the same. You have to compare with epsilon. I would rethink your program architecture if it is dependent of the float staying the exact value. - If it is not used as key and simply a value in a range then scotts recommendation is a valid one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually further testing revealed the following curious outcome: the precision is lost when the DB driver binds the data to the query statement, and *before* the data is actually inserted into the DB.

This has the following interesting consequence: The precision seems to be lost in an identical manner even  when I bind keys to my subsequent search queries, and therefore almost "accidentally" the correct result is returned. That is, the key (coordinates) is stored incorrectly, and then subsequent selects also convert query keys incorrectly, but in a matching manner, and therefore the record is found. Given that the conversions due to precision loss are always performed on the same platform (the server), it's probably safe to leave as is?? Or maybe not, perhaps a future migration exercise (i.e., due to scaling) will make the rounding errors apparent.

Yawar's pointer led me to MySQL's manual which explains that floating point numbers can be stored without loss of precision as DECIMAL:

*"Exact-value numeric literals have an integer part or fractional part, or both. They may be signed"* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html

Given that the existing solution seems to work, the question then becomes, is it better to keep the DB data type `DOUBLE`, or switch to `DECIMAL`?

**Storage:**
`Latitude` has range from `-90 to +90`, and iOS seems to use precision of `14 decimals`
`Longitude` has range from `-180 to +180`, which leaves precision of `13 decimals` on iOS

That means we need:

`Latitude` : `DECIMAL(16,14)`, which takes less the 8 bytes of storage (4 bytes for each pack of 9d)

`Longitude`: `DECIMAL(16,13)`, also requiring less than 8 bytes of storage

In contrast, a column of type `DOUBLE` requires 8 bytes of storage.

**Speed (arithmetic):**
Floating point arithmetic will almost always be materially faster because it is supported natively by the hardware

**Speed (searches):**
I believe index of `DECIMAL` vs index of `DOUBLE` have a very comparable runtime.

**Conclusion:**
Switching to `DECIMAL` eliminates the precision errors and also reduces storage requirements, at an arithmetic performance penalty which is negligible in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing latitude and longitude as double, multiply by 1000000, convert to integer, and store that. Of course, divide by 1000000.0 if you need to read them back in your app.

This will give you plenty of accuracy (0.000001º) for placemarks and will eliminate floating point conversion and precision problems that you are having and take up slightly less space.  I use this in my own data (it's binary, not SQL) and call them MicroDegrees.