# Data Type for storing high precision decimals in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504208/what-mysql-data-type-should-be-used-for-latitude-longitude-with-8-decimal-places), I have a CSV of currency rates which up to 9 decimal places accuracy.

For example : `0.558659218` , `4470.011076` , `7.02E-05`, `0.000641138`, `20832.46989`

Which data type should I use for the column ?

I tried `FLOAT` , `DOUBLE` and `DECIMAL(11,11)`, they produce one of the following warnings:

1. Out of range value for column 'column_name' at row X
2. Value truncated for column 'column_name' at row X

when I use `SHOW WARNINGS` command.

FYI, The SQL statement is as follow (but I guess it is not related):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'currency.csv' INTO TABLE the_currency FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (currency_code, currency_buyin, currency_buyout);
```

Sample data of the CSV is as follow:

```
PHP,41.46218559,0.024118362
PKR,95.71731228,0.010447431
PLN,3.2056255,0.311951599
PYG,4470.011076,0.000223713
QAR,3.641148462,0.274638623
RON,3.524472347,0.283730415
RSD,87.59544136,0.011416119
RUB,31.41607934,0.031830834
RWF,626.1686594,0.001597014
SAR,3.750383024,0.266639432
SBD,7.130814403,0.140236436
SCR,13.08102784,0.076446592
SDG,4.412494807,0.226629162
SEK,6.683528257,0.149621571
SGD,1.221878378,0.81841206
SHP,0.623503208,1.603840987
SLL,4349.905174,0.00022989
SOS,1615.486542,0.000619009
SPL,0.166666667,6
SRD,3.274628066,0.305378193
STD,18949.99968,5.28E-05
SVC,8.75,0.114285714
```

MySQL version: `5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1` and I'm working in console command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `DECIMAL(22,11)` if you want 11 digits *before* as well as *after* the decimal place. `DECIMAL(11,11)` doesn't have any storage for digits *before* the decimal place, and is scarcely even valid at all.

For storing decimal or currency values, `DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC` (largely equivalent) are the way to go. Conversion rates are conceptually a little bit different -- since occasionally, they could be variable by much wider factors -- but `DECIMAL` could be a reasonable place to start, since at least it gives you accurate decimal math results.

The alternative would be `DOUBLE` (`FLOAT` does not have very good precision), which would allow conversion rates between hyper-inflated currencies to be stored;  however, mixing float-point scaling into 'decimal' math requires a well-defined rounding strategy on output.

Comment: Seems I misunderstand (not reading the manual carefully) the definition of `DECIMAL(M,D)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Decimal is what you need. The parameters are length then decimal places. Decimal(length,decimal place)

Example decimal(4,2) =  max value is 99.99
Decimal(6,2) = max value is 9999.99

Hope this helps.