# Database schema for room of a building

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, street-address

I have to create a booking software and I've started to design the database.
The room may be in the any place of the world so I would like to have advice for address.
Reading a lot of similary question I have designed this schema, what do you think about? Is it enough to store all type of addresses?
I followed [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure-tables.html) structure.

[image]

Comment: Why is `FloorNumber` part of `Building`? And for LAT/LONG I’d rather use DECIMAL, to avoid issues with FLOAT inherent imprecision.

Comment: `City VARCHAR(45)` - http://www.fun-with-words.com/longest_place_names.html

Comment: I would consider making City an attribute of Address rather than a separate table. Let users fill this detail in themselves rather than trying to generate a list of every possible city in every country by yourself...

Comment: I update city with VARCHAR(255) and I create city and country as lookup table. FloorNumber containd the number of floors for each building. About LAT/LONG I read about FLOAT(10,6) like google maps, but I read also about geometry. At the momet I updated in according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12504340/4004025

Comment: Can't judge a schema without knowing what `SELECTs` will be performed.  Please sketch them out.

Comment: Do not just `FLOAT(m,n)`; it leads to an extra rounding.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices for deciding on the 'best' representation for lat/long.

Comment: @CBroe - 92 characters in this Russian town; don't know how long in Cyrillic: 'Poselok Uchebnogo Khozyaystva Srednego Professionalno-Tekhnicheskoye Uchilishche Nomer Odin'.  Lat/long: 53.8897/40.6116.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use a 4-byte `INT` for "country_id", use the standard 2-char "country codes"; it is smaller and avoids a `JOIN`.
- There is not really much need to have "city" split out from address -- it does not save enough space to matter, nor is it is useful for "normalization".

So, combine `Country` and `City` into `Address`.

- It is rarely useful to have 1:1 relationships; it is almost always better to merge the two tables into one.  I am thinking about `Building` and `Address`.
- Might you have a billion "floors"?  Don't use 4-byte `INT` when 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED` is more appropriate.  See also `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2 bytes, range of 0..65535).
- DECIMAL(6,4)/(7,4) is all that is needed for lat/long.  8 decimal places is getting into microscopic distances.
- Pick the appropriate `CHARACTER SET`.  `country_code` and (I suspect) `postal_code` can be `ascii` anywhere in the world.  (I could be wrong -- Bangladesh uses non-Arabic numerals on license plates.)  Other `VARCHARs` should probably be `utf8mb4` if you are truly international.

It is good that you read a lot of similar questions to come up with the schema.  It is unfortunate that they were novices.