# What is the correct data type for haversine formula in mySql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, haversine

When I save the longitude and latitude into the database it is stored as datatype Decimal.
The longitude is saved as 34 and the latitude is saved as 118 
will this work with the haversine formula.  I am trying find a locations within 20 miles of the user current location.

Comment: No. You will need greater precision

Comment: How far off will this be? If it is off a mile or two it's ok. And will this haversine formula work with this format?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504208/what-mysql-data-type-should-be-used-for-latitude-longitude-with-8-decimal-places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that definitely won't work.

One degree of latitude is roughly 70 miles. This is much larger than your desired precision.

If you want to calculate distances to a resolution of 20 miles, you'll need at least one decimal place for your latitudes and longitudes -- 0.1° latitude is 7 miles, and 0.1° degree of longitude combined with that is roughly 10 miles (√2 x 7 = 9.8). You'll be better off with as much precision as is available in your source data, of course.

What's probably gone wrong here is that you've used the `DECIMAL` type for your latitude and longitude without specifying a width. In MySQL, this defaults to `DECIMAL(10,0)` -- ten digits, all of them before the decimal place (e.g, `1234567890.`). What you probably want is something more along the lines of `DECIMAL(10,6)`, which allows the column to store a ten-digit number with six of those digits behind the decimal place (e.g, `1234.123456`). [Six decimal places of latitude/longitude gives you a resolution of about 4 inches](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8674), so there's no point in storing any more than that.

Comment: What would be the best way to to do this? Not looking for the code but what approach should I take if decimal is not the right format?

Comment: @dscrown Added some notes on the DECIMAL type.