# What is the best mysql datatype for storing latitudes and Longitudes?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, sqldatatypes

I got confused by the following 2 Questions already asked.

1. [What is the ideal data type to use when storing latitude / longitudes in a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159255/1966247)
2. [What MySQL data type should be used for Latitude/Longitude with 8 decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12504208/1966247)

In the above questions someone is saying that decimal is a good datatype while someone is saying one should use [MySQL's spatial extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html) and others are saying using float is good because Google is also using float in their [application here](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator?csw=1). So what should be the final solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: if you need  only lat and lng as separated  values the best is decimal(12,8)

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks for the comment, you know for some locations google is giving me this value. `39.95467480000001`, `-75.19447579999996` so how can we store this in decimal(12,8).

Comment: decimal(12,8) is  suggestion  if you need  more precision  use a more large  decimal  .. in my project  for my precision i   use   decimal(16,12) ..  this is a precision near millimeter  on google-map

Comment: @scaisEdge I think that is great.

Comment: @scaisEdge can you please give a well detailed answer so that I accept it and help others. Thanks

Comment: Ok .. very gentle .. some some minutes

Comment: answer  posted .. thanks you very much ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

based on my experience   if you need  only lat and lng as seprated  values an otimal solution is based on  data type

```
decimal(16,12)
```

with this format you can localize point on maps with a precision very near to millimeter,  and this for normal maps application is more than enough

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Do the math!  Six decimal places is enough precision to distinguish two lovers kissing.  8 or 12 is ludicrous.  [*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices) is a list of likely choices.

`FLOAT` gives you a resolution of 1.7 meters or 5.6 feet.  `39.95467480000001, -75.19447579999996` is an artifact of the displaying `39.9546748, -75.1944758`.