# How store and lookup 128 vector from face recognition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vector, face-recognition

Im using the following https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition to process images with faces in. Ive used it a few times, but im wanting to get a bit more serious with it, and store a large amount of images and be able to query across them all quickly. So the obvious would to store the 128 Vector in a database. At the moment im wanting to use MySQL as its more in my comfort zone while im learning.

From what i have read i would need to create a column for each of the 128 vectors, and use FLOAT. But i'm cant find anything more on specifics like FLOAT(10,6) etc, or if i need to create any specifics regarding indexes.

The next thing would be then be the Query to search the known vectors with the vectors taken from an image im wishing to search. But i cant find any actual working examples of this.

Comment: There is no `FLOAT(10,6)` but `DECIMAL(10,6)`.

Comment: A while back when storing Long, Lat i read to use FLOAT(10,6) when defining my columns. When googling now i get several posts coming back with FLOAT(10,6) eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504208/what-mysql-data-type-should-be-used-for-latitude-longitude-with-8-decimal-places

Comment: OK sorry, "MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D)". But you probably want to use `DECIMAL` instead. Read the answer from the link in your comment.

Comment: Its just a mathematical formula. But applying this on every row with thousands of images will slow down the performance. Try exploring in memory option. Database can act as a backup where you can restore the encodings from in case of a server restart like situation.