# slower query for searching nearby coordinates

Tags: mysql, coordinates

I seem to hit slower query result for searching nearby coordinates ( for now the query is for latitude). This is a mysql query
select ABS(propertyCoordinatesLat - 3.33234) as diff from tablename order by diff asc limit 0,20

is there a way to improve this besides relying on server scripting to do the sorting?

table dump.

```
CREATE TABLE `property` (
  `propertyID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `propertyName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `propertyCoordinatesLat` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `propertyCoordinatesLng` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `property`
--
ALTER TABLE `property`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`propertyID`),
  ADD KEY `propertyCoordinatesLat` (`propertyCoordinatesLat`,`propertyCoordinatesLng`),
  ADD KEY `propertyCoordinatesLat_2` (`propertyCoordinatesLat`),
  ADD KEY `propertyCoordinatesLng` (`propertyCoordinatesLng`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `property`
--
ALTER TABLE `property`
  MODIFY `propertyID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Could you show us your schema? We'd need to know the column types and indexes.

Comment: just dump it in the OP. not really sure how do i do it. hope that helps

Comment: perhaps latitude should be a numeric type and not a varchar

Comment: Or use the [spacial data types and functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html).

Comment: @lilsizzo That helps a lot, thank you.

Comment: Why are you using varchar for numeric data?

Comment: @Strawberry yeah newbie in that. have changed to numeric. sorting by that still slows the query down

Comment: You haven't changed it :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is ordering by the difference between a string and a float. This odd calculation confuses and angers MySQL and results in a slow filesort.

```
mysql> explain select ABS(propertyCoordinatesLat - 3.33234) as diff from property order by diff 
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key                      | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | property | NULL       | index | NULL          | propertyCoordinatesLat_2 | 302     | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using index; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

Changing `propertyCoordinatesLat` and `propertyCoordinatesLng` to [a more sensible `numeric` type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504208/what-mysql-data-type-should-be-used-for-latitude-longitude-with-8-decimal-places) lets MySQL optimize better. No more filesort. This should perform much better.

```
alter table property change propertyCoordinatesLat propertyCoordinatesLat numeric(10,8) not null;
alter table property change propertyCoordinatesLng propertyCoordinatesLng numeric(11,8) not null;

mysql> explain select ABS(propertyCoordinatesLat - 3.33234) as diff from property order by propertyCoordinatesLat asc limit 0,20;
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key                      | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | property | NULL       | index | NULL          | propertyCoordinatesLat_2 | 5       | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

If you want to get fancy, look into [MySQL's spatial types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html). These will probably perform better, and definitely be more accurate.

Comment: the explain helps alot...but in the actual query, it inner join many other tables.ive made the data type to be decimal. The order by query still slows them down. inner join a table that has 300k tables filtered to 4k plus.

Comment: @lilsizzo Excuse me, did you say ***300,000 tables***? I hope you meant 300,000 rows. Without seeing the real query, can't say what's happening.

Comment: yeah sorry...300k rows...im marking ur answer right as it brought me to the better /right path than i original was