# return items that are within 5km and joining 4 different table mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, coordinates, inner-join

How do i show `items` that are within a 5 kilometer away and below? 
I have 4 database tables which contain informations.

The first table `seller_table` conatine seller informations

The second table `location_table` contains the areas within the country/city seller has a store.

The third table `item_table` contains the product that is available in seller stores.

The last table `item_setting_table` contains item setting per store

```
CREATE TABLE `seller_table` (
    `seller_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `seller_id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `seller_country` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `seller_table` (`seller_name`, `seller_id`, `seller_country`) 
VALUES ('Peter', 'PP1', 'MY'),  
('John', 'JJ6', 'MY'),  
('Paul', 'PL9', 'SG');

CREATE TABLE `location_table` (
    `loc_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `loc_id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `loc_lat` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `loc_lng` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `loc_seller_id` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

 INSERT INTO `location_table` (`loc_name`, `loc_id`, `loc_lat`, `loc_lng`, `loc_seller_id`) 
 VALUES ('Office CYB', '1A', '2.908810', '101.651398', 'PP1'),  
 ('Office NLI', '1B', '2.725806', '101.942375', 'PP1'),
 ('Outlet S', '3A', '3.051953', '101.671455', 'JJ6');

CREATE TABLE `item_table` (
    `item_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `item_id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `item_store_ids` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `item_seller` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

 INSERT INTO `item_table` (`item_name`, `item_id`, `item_store_ids`, `item_seller`) VALUES ('Java', '1', '1A, 1B ', 'PP1'), 
  ('PHP', '2', '1A', 'PP1'), 
  ('CSS', '3', '1B', 'PP1'), 
  ('SQL', '4', '1B', 'PP1'),
  ('Python', '5', '3A', 'JJ6'),
  ('HTML', '6', '1A', 'PP1'),
  ('VUE', '7', '1A', 'PP1');


CREATE TABLE `item_setting_table` (
    `set_item_id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `set_item_status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `set_item_store_id` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `item_setting_table` (`set_item_id`, `set_item_status`, `set_item_store_id`) 
VALUES ('1', 1, '1A'), 
  ('2', 1, '1A'), 
  ('3', 1, '1B'), 
  ('4', 1, '1B'),
  ('5', 1, '3A'),
  ('6', 1, '1A'),
  ('7', 0, '1A');
```

What i actually want to do is to show all product to users within `5.5` kilometer away or less in same country and city, by joining the both 4 tables to check the store location from 'location_table', item status from `item_setting_table`, seller country from `seller_table` and items from `item_table`

I have tried the code but it doesn't return any data or show any error

```
SET @latitude = 2.924860, @longtitude = 101.636941; /*IN RANGE*/
#SET @latitude = 2.802455, @longtitude = 101.79887110000004; /*IN RANGE*/
#SET @latitude = 3.798494, @longtitude = 101.43447100000003; /*OUT OF RANGE*/
SET @KM = 5.5;

SELECT seller.seller_name,loc.loc_name, item.item_name, 
3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((loc.loc_lat - ABS(@latitude)) * PI()/180 / 2), 2) + COS(loc.loc_lng * PI()/180 ) * COS(ABS(@latitude) * PI()/180)  * POWER(SIN((loc.loc_lng - @longtitude) * PI()/180 / 2), 2))) AS distance

FROM item_table item
INNER JOIN seller_table seller
ON item.item_seller = seller.seller_id

INNER JOIN location_table loc
ON loc.loc_id = item.item_store_ids

INNER JOIN item_setting_table sett
ON sett.set_item_id = item.item_id
AND sett.set_item_store_id = item.item_store_ids

WHERE seller.seller_country = "MY"
AND sett.set_item_status = 1
HAVING distance <=  @KM 
OR distance IS NULL
ORDER BY distance IS NULL DESC, distance DESC
LIMIT 100
```

I created a fiiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f6ed6/5/0

Please i really do need help or if have a better way of doing this i will appreciate that

Comment: Why are you storing Latitude and Longitude numerical values as `varchar` ? Check this question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504208/what-mysql-data-type-should-be-used-for-latitude-longitude-with-8-decimal-places

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya is just for this post, i actually used float

Comment: On another note, your query is working fine and I cannot reproduce your issue: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8P8nkRuqLcQkGEwibd4HKw/0

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya please don't use use `ON item.item_seller = seller.seller_id`

Comment: Works fine for me. Fix the data types, and provide the EXPLAIN for the given query. Incidentally, I have a function (geo_distance_km) which reduces the amount of code needed in such queries.

Comment: In your item_table, you still have multiple store ids. ```('Java', '1', '1A, 1B ', 'PP1')```

Comment: @Strawberry From your query, the first location which is Office CYB returns  `PHP, HTML` and from Office NLI returns `SQL, CSS`. But what i actual want is to return all item in both location and control the availability from `setting table` `PHP,CSS,SQL,HTML` except `VUE` which the status is 0.

Comment: @JitendraYadav that how i tried before to implement it, store ids in array. But it didn't work. that why i am trying another method.