# How to store (latitude, longitude, altitude) tuple in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, tuples, latitude-longitude, altitude

There are [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12504340/1084174) to store latitude and longitude as `Point` in `MySQL` database, but how can I store a tuple for (`latitude`, `longitude`, `altitude`) in `MySQL` database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a POINT for the latitude and longitude, and a DECIMAL for the altitude:

```
CREATE TABLE Mountain (
  Location POINT NOT NULL,  -- Latitude/longitude
  Altitude DECIMAL(12, 2)   -- Altitude or height in meters or feet or furlongs if you prefer
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

or, just use three decimals - one for latitude, one for longitude, one for altitude:

```
CREATE TABLE Mountain (
  Latitude   DECIMAL(10, 7),
  Longitude  DECIMAL(10, 7),
  Altitude   DECIMAL(11, 1)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: 7 is a bit of overkill.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices

Comment: @RickJames: there's no kill like overkill. :-) If you store degrees-minutes-seconds you're down to 100 feet, so seconds-to-two-decimal-places gets you down to one-foot accuracy - so seven decimal places is 1/10 of a foot accuracy and I can't shoot much straighter'n that anyways! :-)